# An all-pass filter with 0 degrees to +180 degrees shift

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter

I need an (for audio bandwidth) all-pass filter that has 0 degrees shift in low frequency and +180 degrees shift at high frequency.

The ones here https://sound-au.com/articles/active-filters.htm (figure 7.5) do just the reverse.
[image: All-pass filters from Rod Elliot's site]

Can somebody please post a schematic or link to an op-amp based implementation?

Comment: Please include the schematic in your post so your readers don't have to follow a link to understand your question. Leave the link there to acknowledge the source. There's an [edit] link below your question.

Comment: +180 at high frequencies is non-causal. If you really need to do this, you'll just have to run time backwards. (Consider if there's a way to approximate what you need with the classic all-pass you found and an inverter).

Comment: @BrianDrummond It might not be the first time I meet someone meaning to say -180, instead of the +180. Maybe OP meant it negative?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen if that were so, the linked solution would suit his purpose.

Comment: @wonderfullot. I rejected your edit of my post as you were trying to start a conversation in my post. That's not how this site (or any other site I've ever seen) works. My post is now deleted.

Comment: Rod Eliott's site gives examples of these two situations:-
a) 0 degrees at lows and -180 at highs
b) 180 degrees at lows and 0 degrees at highs
If you note, the lows are always leading .

What I need is one of below:-
a) -180 degrees at lows and 0 degrees at highs
b) 0 degrees at lows and +180 degrees at highs.
If you note, I need the lows to lag.

Comment: @Transistor, I am new to this site and this is my 1st post. Actually I tried to edit my question and didn't intend to edit your post but ended up doing exactly that, I didn't know how to undo that, my bad. Your post actually helped make my question clear, you could have been softer.